# LINQ query join only last value

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq, join

I am making a ASP.NET C# library system. Het a screenshot of the (MSSQL) DB-design:
[image: DB-design:]

To display the books, I use the Rentals table.
But there is **my problem**:

- I left join the Books table with the Rentals table (because also books who are not yet rented once, need to be displayed (*see book with id 3*)
- When I just do left join, I see my books offcourse multiple times in my books-overview...
- **SO**: I should need a LINQ query that joins Books with Rentals, but if the books are already been rented multiples times, he should only **join** with the **last value in the table of that book_id**
- Look at the image below: The query should only select the green-selected values...
- *(extra info: if someone rent a book, the returned value = 0, if he returns the book, it becomes 1)*

[image: Example data of tables]

The query I have now is:

```
var query = (from b in db.Books
                     join a in db.Authors on b.author_id equals a.author_id
                     join c in db.Categories on b.category_id equals c.category_id
                     join r in db.Rentals on b.book_id equals r.book_id into lf
                     from r in lf.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     select new BookDetails(
                                b.book_id,
                                b.title,
                                b.ISBN,
                                b.description,
                                b.author_id,
                                a.firstName,
                                a.lastName,
                                b.category_id,
                                r.returned == null ? 1 : r.returned)
                     ).ToList();
```

But like I said, this displays me rented books multiple times...
I've been thinking about something with the "MAX" property? (but does this works with linq?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group the books by book ID and then select first item from each group. That's a neat way how to simulate "distinct". In your case that would be

```
var query = (from b in db.Books
             join a in db.Authors on b.author_id equals a.author_id
             join c in db.Categories on b.category_id equals c.category_id
             join r in db.Rentals on b.book_id equals r.book_id into lf
             from r in lf.DefaultIfEmpty()
             group new{ Book = b, Author = a, Rental = r }
                 by b.book_id into booksById
             let item = booksById.First()
             select new BookDetails(
                 item.Book.book_id,
                 item.Book.title,
                 item.Book.ISBN,
                 item.Book.description,
                 item.Book.author_id,
                 item.Author.firstName,
                 item.Author.lastName,
                 item.Book.category_id,
                 item.Rental.returned == null
                     ? 1 : item.Rental.returned))
             .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! How can I get at 'a' and 'r' in the select new BookDetails? They don't exists anymore there...

Comment: Oh, you're right, you'll have to add them to the aggregate. I'll edit my answer.